# Maximum number of common neighbors in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Consider an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$. I'd like to find a subset $R \subseteq V$, $|R|=m$ s.t. its elements have the maximum number of common neighbors in $G$. What algorithms do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any idea or a set of algorithms where to choose from? I don't think divide and conquer or a greedy algorithm would work here. Honestly, I might be wrong, but to me it sounds like an NP problem.

Comment: Does this mean you sum up, for each pair $\{i,j\}\subseteq R$, the number of nodes $k\in V$ for which both $\{i,k\}\in E$ and $\{j,k\}\in E$?

Comment: Yes, exactly @RobPratt !

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For each node $i\in N$, let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether $i$ is selected to appear in $R$.  For each node pair $(i,j)\in N \times N$ with $i<j$, let $c_{i,j}=|\{k\in V: \{\{i,k\},\{j,k\}\}\subseteq E\}|$ be the number of common neighbors $k$ of $i$ and $j$, and let $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether nodes $i$ and $j$ appear in $R$.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} y_{i,j}$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i &= m\\
y_{i,j} &\le x_i\\
y_{i,j} &\le x_j
\end{align}